# Javascript Touch event on Ipad is returning radiusX=radiusY=0 always

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ipad, safari

Javascript Touch event on Ipad is returning radiusX=radiusY always. Is there a way to get more precise raw data from the ipad about the touch in the browser?

```
touch.radiusX = 0  touch.radiusY = 0 `irrespective of the size of my touch`
```

PS. I have no preference for the browser I use.